# Web Deploy 4 gives 404, Web Deploy 3.6 works while not changing anything else

Tags: iis, web-deployment, webdeploy

(If you have no time, jump to the Question. The essence is there)

I am battleing this since more than a year with no success. Please note: All prerequisites for web deploy are triple checked set... keep reading.

I would like to publish ASP.NET Core 6 Web App to Windows Server 2019 or 2022. (the issue is exactly the same for both versions)

I enable IIS features via PowerShell using the following commands:

```
Install-WindowsFeature Web-Server -IncludeManagementTools
Install-WindowsFeature Web-Mgmt-Service
Install-WindowsFeature Web-Scripting-Tools
Install-WindowsFeature Web-Mgmt-Tools
```

**After this if I go to Add or Remove Programs, I see Web Deploy 4 is installed**

I also check the following

- Web Management Service is Running
- `Test-NetConnection <server ip> -Port 8172` so connection if working end to end
- Remote management is enabled
- No handler is needed, (so not configured), please keep reading

With this configuration VS 2022 Publish gives me http 404

If I reinstall Web Deploy 4 (in Add or Remove programs, "Repair") the issue still remains

**Question**

If I uninstall Web Deploy 4 and install Web Deploy 3.6 *and do nothing else* all works fine.
I tried this at least ten times in different Windwos 2019 and Windows 2022 Servers...
Any hint, how can make Web Deploy 4 work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a surprise.

It seems to me the Web Deploy 4 (shipped as part of Visual Studio) by default does not install any server side components onto IIS. The goal seems to limit Web Deploy 4 usage to only client side (publishing to a remote server with Web Deploy 4 installed, such as Azure App Service).

Web Deploy 3.6 installer, however, seems to install both client/server components by default.

According to limited information, 3.6 server components are usually enough for end users, so no need to upgrade to 4.0.

Comment: Many thanks, you are completely right. Meanwhile myself too. also realized, that VS 2022 is responsible for having Web Deploy 4 installed, not the Windows Server components I listed in the OP. However with the undesirable side effect, that having Web Deploy 4 installed is effectively preventing Web Deploy 3.6 installer to run, it exits with the error message, a newer version is installed... which is true for the client side, but not the server side components. So the only solution is uninstalling Web Deploy 4 then installing Web Deploy 3.6 either via choco either downloading the MS installer.